# Two scheduled Python Scripts that update tables in SQL Server - both run without error, one does not update its table

Tags: python, sql-server, windows-task-scheduler, windows-server-2019

(This same scenario happens on 4 different servers - Windows Server 2019)

I have two Python3 scripts, each running under separate Windows Task Scheduler tasks.

Details:

1. Task 1 runs Script 1 - Task 2 Runs Script 2 (genericizing for this question)
2. Both scripts use identical credentials for both Windows task Scheduler tasks
3. Both scripts use identical credentials for SQL Server
4. Both scripts update tables in the same SQL Server database (credentials have same rights for both tables)
5. Both scripts run without error (RC 0)
6. Task 1 - Script 1 should update Table A
7. Task 2 - Script 2 should update Table B
8. Running under Windows Task Scheduler

   - Task1/Script1/Table A gets updated
   - Task2/Script2/Table B does NOT (as stated previously, no errors)
9. Other steps in the scripts - before and after the SQL update statements - run fine and do what they are supposed to do.
10. If I run Task 2/Script 2 with the Task Scheduler "RUN" button - the table is updated without issue.

Everything from a credentials aspect is absolutely identical.  If I export the Windows task scheduler tasks and view them side-by-side - they are identical (other than the script name and the scheduled run time) [No errors as stated before :-)  Just want that to be clear - RC 0 on the script that is not updating its table]

Nothing in Windows event logs to indicate an issue

=> The SQL statements are virtually identical and as stated above - update just fine when clicking "RUN". <= (This is what is so strange)

I tried running as Windows 2008 (in task scheduler) - no difference (trying anything at this point)

It is only when running as scheduled that one of the tables does not get updated (the same task/script/table each time - on four different servers).

I have recreated the tasks on all four servers, etc. - Same issue.

I am stumped at this point.

Can anyone point me in a direction that I have not explored yet that might shed some light on this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The four different servers are in different regions and all had the same scheduled clock time for runs - no issue since they are all in different time zones.

Apparently, (unbeknownst to me), an effort has been underway to move all devices to UTC time - regardless of location - so now all of my servers have the same clock time.  Thus, all four servers were running the scripts at the exact same time and creating a lock on the database.

I did not receive any errors that I could see and the remainder of my script executed as expected.

I did not suspect locking because with the different time zones, the scripts should have been running on local time and they should not have overlapped.

I have since staggered the run times and I am seeing data in the tables as expected.